# How can I disable X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff for only one web page?

Tags: php, apache

For a web page using CSS `<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styjes.css" />` issues an error MIME type mismatch in the browser due to the 'nosniff' setting in Apache. The latter is required due to security, but for one webpage I want to make an exception by putting a line like `X-Content-Type-Options=xxxx` which allows loading the css and just ignores the nosniff. I can put this line into an .htaccess file or adding a PHP `header("X-Content-Type-Options: xxxx")` where xxxx should be something like 'sniff' or 'none'.

Does someone know that option ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no "anti-sniff" option. That header is either set or it isn't. Take a look at the [corresponding Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options).
Since `text/css` is the correct mime type for stylesheets, I'd suggest that there's another problem in your application. First thing that comes to mind is a typo in your path specification. I'm sure it should be "styles.css", not "styjes.css".